# How to get all the heads of the current branch?

Tags: mercurial

Is there an easy way of getting all the heads of current branch?

Currently I get the current branch name with `hg branch` and after that perform `hg heads branchname`.

So is there any shortcut to `current branch name` to prevent of using 2 commands?

PS: in bash we can do

```
hg heads `hg branch`
```

but is there native and cross-platform mercurial solution using revision set language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TBT!

- `hg heads -r "min(branch(.))`  <strike>and branch(.)</strike>"(min() because "If STARTREV is specified, only those heads that are **descendants of STARTREV** will be displayed.")
- `hg log -r "head() and branch(.)"`

Comment: TBT? Btw, first returns all the heads (at least when I run it in `default`), the second works

Comment: @zerkms - "To Be Tested", when I'm not sure in final result and write draft

Answer (score 5):

Yes, use

```
$ hg heads .
```

The `hg heads` command takes an optional revision identifier. If you run `hg heads X`, you will get the heads of the branch of `X` — note the extra indirection. This means that you can use `.` (which means the working copy parent revision) to get heads on the current branch.

Comment: Ah, so simple, so elegant.

Comment: Hi Martin, Did you mean to write "the heads of the branch `X`"? In other words, doesn't the branch have the name `X` in your example?